# Why would a simple JS undefined check trigger an error?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm looping through a large object where the internal properties are not all consistent. However, when I throw an `if(typeof){}` statement around the object, it's still triggering an error:

**The statement**

```
if (typeof pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i].trip.id !== "undefined") {// do stuff}
```

**The error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trip' of undefined
```

**The catch**

However, a sister object sitting in the same function *with the same scope* does just fine.

```
if (typeof pendingTripPickupMarkers[i].trip.id !== "undefined") {// do stuff}
```

If I do a print of object contents after they are created, they look just fine. So what evil force has a hand here? Thanks.

Comment: Object property resolution does not involve scope. Scope is about variable (identifier) resolution, object properties are resolved on the object and its internal Prototype chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test *any* objects that have potential of being undefined.

```
if (pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i] 
       && pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i].trip
       && pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i].trip.id !== undefined) {
```

---

If you're really worried about `undefined` being overwritten, don't do the `typeof` hack. Just get a fresh `undefined` using the `void` operator.

```
if (pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i] 
       && pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i].trip
       && pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i].trip.id !== void 0) {
```

---

If you're certain that `pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i]` should be defined, then there's some other issue somewhere.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, the higher level object was undefined!

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you that `pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i]` is undefined, since it "cannot read the `trip` property of  *undefined*"

It IS NOT necessarily true that `pendingTripDropoffMarkers` or `pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i]` are null.  Indeed, both propositions are almost certainly false.   At least`pendingTripDropoffMarkers` must be previously defined and not null, because it's not complaining about getting some object indexed off of it.  If `pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i]` was null, the error would be something like "cannot read the trip property of *null*", not "cannot read the trip property of *undefined*"

If, on the other hand, `i` were out of range for the `pendingTripDropoffMarkers` array, `pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i]` would be undefined.  So I'd wager that's the case, if indeed was defined as an array.

That doesn't mean it's true though! You can still make weird things like

```
var myarray = [undefined,2];
```

in which case `myarray[0]` would be undefined, and trying to get `trip` off of that would get the same error.  But that's a very weird case.

Comment: Perhaps uncommon, but not weird. Elisions are included in the language so that sparse arrays can be created using literals: `[,,2,3]` creates an array of length 4, but there are no members for indexes `0` and `1`, attempting to access them will return *undefined*, they don't exists at all (e.g. `array.hasOwnProperty('0')` returns *false*).

Comment: It's a strange object but I did test the weird undefined case because apparently there are some edge cases where this is happening. So although your answer doesn't solve the bigger picture, you did save me from a future problem :)

Comment: @JayC: Who claimed that something was `null`?

Answer (score 1):

If  `pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i]` is null you will get the error.  i.e., you are not checking if the array element exists before testing things **in** the array element...

I usually do something like the following, for readability:

```
var currentElement = pendingTripDropoffMarkers[i],
    elementExists  = currentElement != null,
    hasId          = elementExists && currentElement.trip && currentElement.trip.id

if (elementExists && hasId) {...}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `!=` for your `elementExists` test? You're currently using a strict test, so if it `!== null`, it could still be `undefined`

Comment: that's true, and thanks for pointing it out....that's why I said 'something like the following' ;)  Heck he just do `elementExists = currentElement` if all he cared about was it being truthy

Comment: The problem here is that currentElement is triggering errors and probably because it's accessing that trip.id. am not i am's solution was able to solve this problem, but i'll remember this since i'd like to try this on other functions